# Sorting an array. input--> [3,4,5,1,2] Expected_output--->[5,2,3,1,4]

Tags: java, arrays

`Input: nums = [3, 4, 5, 1, 2]`

`Output: nums = [5, 2, 3, 1, 4]`

Explanation: In this example, we have even numbers `[4, 2]` located at positions `[1, 4]`.

They are sorted in ascending order and placed back in their original positions. The odd numbers `[3, 1, 5]` are originally at positions `[0, 2, 3]`, and they are arranged in descending order while maintaining their original positions.

I tried but i Got `[5,2,3,4,1]`
how to get expected output `[5,2,3,1,4]`

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class BubbleSorting {
    
    static void bubbleSort(ArrayList<Integer> list, Boolean Bool) {
        int n = list.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++) {
                if(Bool==true) {
                if (list.get(j) > list.get(j + 1)) {
                    // Swap elements if they are in the wrong order
                    int temp = list.get(j);
                    list.set(j, list.get(j + 1));
                    list.set(j + 1, temp);
                }
                }
                else {
                    if (list.get(j) < list.get(j + 1)) {
                        // Swap elements if they are in the wrong order
                        int temp = list.get(j);
                        list.set(j, list.get(j + 1));
                        list.set(j + 1, temp);
                }
            }
          }
        
      }
    }

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] num = {3,4,5,1,2};
        ArrayList<Integer> even = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> odd = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0; i<num.length; i++) {
            if (num[i]%2==0) {
                even.add(num[i]);
            }
            else {
                odd.add(num[i]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Before_sort"+odd);
        System.out.println("Before_sort"+even);
        bubbleSort(odd, false);
        bubbleSort(even, true);
        System.out.println("after_sort"+odd);
        System.out.println("after_sort"+even);
        
        int[] combinedArray = new int[5];
        int currentIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < Math.max(odd.size(), even.size()); i++) {
            if (i < odd.size()) {
                combinedArray[currentIndex++] = odd.get(i);
            }
            if (i < even.size()) {
                combinedArray[currentIndex++] = even.get(i);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(combinedArray));
    }

}
```

Comment: Is this question from you as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77799109/sorting-an-arraydesc-for-odd-asce-for-even

Comment: yes @seenukarthi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are complicating things without need. I assume that since you named your method bublesort, you want to implement a buble sort algorithm. Just iterate over your array and check if the current element is even or odd. If odd, look for the next odd element in the array and compare them and if applicable swap the elements. If even exactly the same, search for the next even element and compare:

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int array[] = {3, 4, 5, 1, 2};
        sortOddDescEvenAsc(array);
    }

    public static void sortOddDescEvenAsc(int array[]) {

        int[] sortedArray = new int[array.length];
        System.arraycopy(array, 0, sortedArray, 0, array.length);

        for (int i = 0; i < sortedArray.length - 1; i++) {
            /* is current element odd, if yes search next odd element*/
            if (sortedArray[i] % 2 != 0) {
                /* search for next odd and compare */
                for (int j = i + 1; j < sortedArray.length; j++) {
                    /* odd descending */
                    if ((sortedArray[j] % 2 != 0) && (sortedArray[i] < sortedArray[j])) {
                        int temp = sortedArray[i];
                        sortedArray[i] = sortedArray[j];
                        sortedArray[j] = temp;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                /* current element is even! search for next even and compare*/
                for (int j = i + 1; j < sortedArray.length; j++) {
                    /* even ascending */
                    if ((sortedArray[j] % 2 == 0) && (sortedArray[i] > sortedArray[j])) {
                        int temp = sortedArray[i];
                        sortedArray[i] = sortedArray[j];
                        sortedArray[j] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i : sortedArray) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is quite the right approach. First separate odds and even elements into lists and sort them out ascending and descending respectively. And then merge them while keeping the track of the original array. Here's my approach with using Java Collection's sorting (not using bubble sort though) :

```html
int[] sort(int[] nums) {
    List<Integer> evens = new ArrayList<>(), odds = new ArrayList<>();

    // Separating odd and even elements
    for (int num : nums) {
      if (num % 2 == 0) {
        evens.add(num);
      } else {
        odds.add(num);
      }
    }

    // even numbers ascending
    Collections.sort(evens);

    // odd numbers descending
    Collections.sort(odds, Collections.reverseOrder());

    // merging odd and even to a new array according to 
    // their occurence in the original array
    int[] result = new int[nums.length];
    int evenIndex = 0, oddIndex = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
      if (nums[i] % 2 == 0) {
        result[i] = evens.get(evenIndex);
        evenIndex++;
      } else {
        result[i] = odds.get(oddIndex);
        oddIndex++;
      }
    }
    return result;
 }
```

In the merging process, I have kept different indices for odd and even lists (you have used a single index 'i' for that purpose).

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < Math.max(odd.size(), even.size()); i++) {
        if (i < odd.size()) {
            combinedArray[currentIndex++] = odd.get(i);
        }
        if (i < even.size()) {
            combinedArray[currentIndex++] = even.get(i);
        }
    }
```

this code doesn't allow you to maintain the actual order of the even odd values, instead you are just adding 1 odd, 1 even in a loop

so fix the issue, you need to do -

```
int[] combinedArray = new int[5];
    int oddIndex = 0;
    int evenIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <combinedArray.length ; i++) {
        if (num[i]%2==1) {
            combinedArray[i] = odd.get(oddIndex++);
        }
        else {
            combinedArray[i] = even.get(evenIndex++);
        }
    }
```

Your bubble sort is already maintaining the order. Then, if any index contains odd, then put odd in that position and vice versa. This will maintain the index order too.